# Unexpected end of file error while opening a file via os.system

Tags: python

```
 f = urllib.urlopen(url) #Download the file


 localFile = open(url.split('/')[-1],'w')

 localFile.write(f.read())
 os.system("transmission %s" %localFile)
```

Error I get is this:

```
sh: Syntax error: end of file unexpected
512
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem might be that `localfile` contains some confusing characters which make the shell think it should get further information.

Try out if

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['transmission', localFile])
```

changes the situation.

---

EDIT: This is, of course, nonsense.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['transmission', url.split('/')[-1]])
```

should be the way to go, with storing `url.split('/')[-1]` into a variable which then can replace the two occurrences of that expression.

Nevertheless, the usage of `os.system()` can be dangerous. Better stay with `subprocess.call()`.

Comment: It worked. But had to some changes to it. Rather than going for subprocess.call(['transmission', localFile]), I went for subprocess.call(['transmission', url]).

Comment: Why would the usage of os.system be dangerous? Curious, as I use it frequently in my work.

Comment: The filename you give might contain characters which make the interpretation of the command line different to what you imagined. Beware that on UNIX-like systems, a filename is allowed to contain all characters except the `NUL` byte and `/` (as the latter is used for path separation). If your file is now named `; rm -rf ~`, you happen to execute `transmission ; rm -rf ~` which is probably not at all what you want.

Answer (score 2):

the `localFile` variable does not contain a filename but a file handle. a file handle is a numeric value which identifies the file and is only valid in the current executing process. but `transmission` awaits a filename as its argument, not a file handle.

try using the filename as the argument to `transmission` when calling `os.system()`:

```
filename = url.split('/')[-1]

localFile = open(filename,'w')
localFile.write(f.read())
localFile.close()

os.system("transmission %s" %(filename,))
```

*(also, do not forget to close the file when you are finished writing its data)*

Comment: Yes. I got my mistake. Thank you for the prompt reply. Rectified it.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you are doing what you want?

I see that you open a file and call system command `transmission <open file 'somename', mode 'w' at 0x16824b0>`, or at least that's what you get by converting file d. to string according to me, that doesn't make so much sense to me